# Monday New York session opening price at 00:00 on any timeframe and at any time

Tags: pine-script

How can I get the opening price of the 00:00 New York hourly candle (Monday only) on any timeframe at any time?

I tried to adapt this code but due to the way the "ta.valuewhen" function is implemented the code only works on lower time frames (from a minute to an hour)

```
f_get_timestamp_open_price(t) =>
    start_date = time >= t
    first_bar = not start_date[1] and start_date
    ta.valuewhen(first_bar, open, 0)

t = timestamp("America/New_York", year, month, dayofweek.monday, 0, 0, 0) 
test = f_get_timestamp_open_price(t)
log.info("\nMonday 00:00 = " + str.tostring(test))
```

obviously this price is not what I want:

```
WOpen=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", open)
```

**update**

I also tried this solution:

```
var WOpen = 0.0
WOpen := (hour == 0 and minute == 0 and dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday) ? open : WOpen
log.info("timeframe="+timeframe.period+" Price="+str.tostring(WOpen))
```

as you can see the price is correct on smaller timeframes

```
[2023-10-06T10:37:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=1 Price=1.21901
[2023-10-06T10:25:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=5 Price=1.21901
[2023-10-06T10:41:00.608+02:00]: timeframe=15 Price=1.21901
[2023-10-06T07:00:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=60 Price=1.21901
```

but on timeframes longer than 60 minutes the price is lost

```
[2023-10-06T03:00:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=120 Price=0
[2023-10-05T23:00:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=240 Price=0
[2023-10-02T23:00:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=D Price=0
[2023-10-01T23:00:00.000+02:00]: timeframe=W Price=0
```

where am I wrong?